# order stderr and stdout or flush stderr

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

i got the following batch command

```
echo 1 & echo 2 1>&2 & echo 3
```

sometimes this prints 1 2 3
and sometimes 132 how can I control the order?
I must have the order.

is there a command that enables the following?

```
echo 1 & echo 2 1>&2 & flush_stderr() & echo 3
```

Comment: Where the output goes? All into the same prompt window?

Comment: Interesting problem, but I can't reproduce the behavior on my machine.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; 1 2 3 is always shown here... However, this _may_ solve your problem: `echo 1 & (echo 2 1>&2 | pause>nul) & echo 3`

Answer (score 2):

If you use `&&` instead of `&`, it will only proceed to the next command if the previous one completed successfully. In that sense, you can ensure a specific progression.

My belief is that in some cases when you run the line, one of the latter commands completes sooner than an earlier one because they are all initiated at virtually the same time.

Edit: Another solution (albeit more verbose) would be to run a `start /wait` for each command.
I.e., `start "" /b /wait cmd /c "echo 1" & start "" /b /wait cmd /c "echo 2" 1>&2 & start "" /b /wait cmd /c "echo 3"`

Comment: Also the `&` operator lets one command execute *after* the other; the described problem seems to be related to data buffers...

Comment: That's a good point. I'll add an alternative (albeit more tacky) solution I recently came to. If you are able to explain more specifically how data buffers play into it, that may be helpful for myself and other readers.